# FizzBuzzWoofFooBar

Tags: c++, fizzbuzz

My C++ was starting to get rusty and I never touched some of the newer features. Reason enough to try something simple and make it overly complicated:

FizzBuzz with bonus features. For now we'll call it FizzBuzzWoofFooBar.

The FizzBuzz idea is to check whether an integer is dividable by 3 and/or 5, the first two primes after 2. I decided to expand on that and check for 3, 5, 7, 9 and 13. However, the current method isn't as generic as I think I could be. Usually I'd try it OO, but that seems overkill for this situation.

I'm specifically looking for suggestions to add more genericalism (that should be a word) without too much of a speed penalty. My variables should probably be named better as well, I'm not very creative.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::string output(int);

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15016; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << output(i) << '\n';
    }
    std::cin.get();
}

std::string output(int i)
{
    std::string print;
    std::map<int, std::string> dict = { { 3, "Fizz" }, { 5, "Buzz" }, { 7, "Woof" }, { 11, "Foo" }, { 13, "Bar" } };
    typedef std::map<int, std::string>::iterator mapIterator;

    for (auto const &j : dict)
    {
        if (i % j.first == 0)
        {
            print += j.second;
        }
    }
    if (print == "")
    {
        print += std::to_string(i);
    }
    return print;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your code looks pretty good. For me the map is a much nicer option than a chain of `if` tests, though it might perform slower than `if`s for such a short number of outcomes.

I don't have much to comment here, only some nitpicking:

- Any particular reason behind `15016`?

  > ```
  > for (int i = 0; i < 15016; ++i)
  > ```

  Either a comment or a self explanatory named constant would be in order here.
- Since this consists of a single source file program, I would avoid declaring function prototypes and would place every function above `main()`. This simplifies maintenance since function prototypes force you to update two places instead of one when a change is needed. Granted that you only have one other function, so this is not a big deal in this case.
- Not a big deal again, but you could typedef `std::map<int, std::string>` since this is a fairly long template declaration and used in two places. But wait, `mapIterator` is declared and never used! Which drops the type usage to a single (useful) place, making the typedef ultimately unnecessary.
- The map (`dict`) is not meant to be modified after being declared. You should enforce single assignment with `const`. Breaking the line where you initialize it would probably also improve readability.

  ```
  const std::map<int, std::string> dict = { 
      { 3,  "Fizz" }, 
      { 5,  "Buzz" }, 
      { 7,  "Woof" }, 
      { 11, "Foo"  }, 
      { 13, "Bar"  } 
  };
  ```
- To avoid creating and destroying a new `map dict` at every call of `output()`, you can either pass a pre-existent instance as a function parameter or just declare the map as `static` inside the function. This could add some performance benefits if the function is called a lot (not sure if you would notice a big hit with just `15016` though).
- `output()` should probably be `fizzBuzzWoofFooBar()` or similar. "Output" is very vague and could mean a function outputting whatever. In the context presented here, it is easy to figure out what it outputs, but it would be a terrible name in any larger program. `i` and `j` are arguably weak names for those variables as well, but I can't think of anything better either...

Comment: You have a very good points. The `mapIterator` was part of the program but didn't make it in the end. Not sure why it's still there and why I didn't see it. `for (int i = 0; i < 15016; ++i)` becomes obvious when running the code. 15015 is the first number printing 'FizzBuzzWoofFooBar`.